# Shmitah nowadays?

Tags: halacha, shmita, modern-times

Do any poskim hold that there isn't shmita now days?
I ask this because

1. There is a machloket rishonim if the yovel counts towards shmita or
   not.
2. There are opinions that say only when we have the Beit Hamikdash is shmita deorita.

Therefore it seems like a safek sefka (doubt within a doubt).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Everyone says it's either deoraita or derabanan. What's the second safek?

Comment: "safek sefka" does not mean 2 doubts, but "a doubt within a doubt". You have given us 2 parallel (if not identical) doubts.

Comment: For one widely accepted poseq's view, see Yalqut Yosef's Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, [Yoreh De'ah 331:9](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_63.html#סימןBשלאB-BפרקBא'B-BיסודותBמצותBהשמיטהB‏-ט) that "most posqim consider Shemitah today to be Mi'De'Rabbanan"

Comment: The _s'fek s'feka_ seems, @DannySchoemann, DoubleAA, to be that even if _sh'mita_ is a divinely imposed obligation nowadays, we're unsure what year it is (because of the other _safek_). Seems reasonable to me (especially if the asker can source his/her _s'fekos_), at least on the face of it.

Comment: @DannySchoemann You're right -- "double doubt" was my translation for the benefit of people who don't know what it means.....that would only be understandable to people who know what it means. Now fixed.

Comment: @msh210 I'm not following. What is the conclusion you draw from this SS? "even if sh'mita is a divinely imposed obligation nowadays, we're unsure what year it is" and therefore it doesn't exist? How does deoraita/derabanan play in?

Comment: I don't believe the argument of s'fek s'feka can apply in this case.  No sources, but consider the very similar case of doing d'rabanan stuff on second day yom tov.  We *know* it's d'rabanan (so kal vachomer to this case), yet there is no blanket permission to do d'rabanans on either day.  Similar case is not knowing when shabbas is in the desert, any place that has dateline issues, or the question of counting twice for the Omer in chutz-laaretz.  In all those cases we choose one day to be "official", and keep the rules on that day.

Comment: @msh210 - which Poskim don't agree with our count of Shmita? (And if that's the OP's first doubt, it should be made more explicit.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann It's a longstanding Machloket Rishonim (see Tur CM 67). Some people are going to write Prozbuls next week because of it and there were minhagim not long ago to not say a Bracha on Pidyon Maaser Sheni because of it.

Comment: @DoubleAA (re your reply to my comment) and therefore it doesn't exist this year.

Comment: @msh Can you elaborate on your logical process: why does a doubt lead to it not existing and how is the principle of sfek sfeka utilized in arriving at that conclusion?

Comment: @DoubleAA: the Tur does NOT say that. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40383&st=&pgnum=222

Comment: @DoubleAA: The Tur does NOT say that the Safek of the year is the reason for the machlokes if you need a prozbul before the end of the 6th or 7ht year.The ROSH, Rabbeinu Yerucham and Ba'al HaItur are of the opinion that you transgress Lo Yigoth during the 7th year already - even though the loan only expires at the end of the 7th. A Prozbul solves  the לא יגוש issue. Note that the TUR mentions the date issue after the above issue. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40383&st=&pgnum=222 .

Comment: @DoubleAA - besides, the TUR says we Pasken like the earlier year, so according to your logic we should write a prozbul in the 7th and 8th/1st year to be on the safe side. (See the Bet Yosef that the TUR we have has a typo.)

Comment: Sorry I was away for a bit.

Comment: Sorry I was away for a bit. My first Mekor for the safeq is based of the Gemara Rosh Hashana 9A. Its a Mahloket between Hachamim and R.Yehuda. Hachamim say Yovel does not count as first year, and R.Yehuda says it does. The rishonim debate who the Halacha follows. The Rambam goes like Hachamim, but the geonim differ. This mahloket has big nafka minot of when shmita is. The other safek is if shmitta is derabban based of the gemara in Moed Katan 2b. Rebbe says that shmitta is deraban. And the rambam copys Rebbes words in Mishneh Torah. So even if its not a safek sefeka, its a safek derabanan.

Comment: Can anybody answer according to my last comment?

Comment: @Yishaq but now we do not have Yovel, so anyway there should not be a difference between Hcachamim and R. Yehuda.

Comment: But the last Yovel that took place, caused every following shmitah to appear diffently in the eyes of Hachamim vs R.Yehuda

Comment: @Yishaq The fact that Tannaim argue about a rabbinic law does not make it a safek derabanan. There's this thing we have called "Psak"...

Comment: There you go again with your loud posts Double AA. I wrote three three posts ago "The rishonim debate who the Halacha follows". Hopefully you psak of rishonim.

Answer (score 1):

The Remo mentions it in Shulchan Aruch Choshen Mishpat [סימן סז - דין שמטה ופרוזבול](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01977_part_3.html#HtmpReportNum0028_L2).

To quote:

> אֲבָל יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים **דְּאֵין שְׁמִטָּה נוֹהֶגֶת בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה**; וְנִרְאֶה שֶׁעֲלֵיהֶם סָמְכוּ בִּמְדִינוֹת אֵלּוּ, **שֶׁאֵין נוֹהֲגִים דִּין שְׁמִטָּה כְּלָל בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה**, וְהַמִּנְהָג הָיוּ נוֹהֲגִים עֲדַיִן בִּזְמַן הָרֹא''שׁ, כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב בִּתְשׁוּבָה (הַטּוּר ס''ה הֵבִיאוֹ), שֶׁהָיָה צוֹוֵחַ כִּכְרוּכְיָא לְבַטֵּל הַמִּנְהָג, וְלֹא אַשְׁגָּחוּ בֵהּ, וּכְבָר כָּתְבוּ גַם כֵּן הָאַחֲרוֹנִים ז''ל (בד''מ ס''ה הֵבִיאוֹ)  טַעַם לַמִּנְהָג **שֶׁאֵין נוֹהֲגִין שְׁמִטָּה** כַּמְבֹאָר בְּדִבְרֵי מַהֲרִי''ק שֹׁרֶשׁ צ''ב וּמהר''ר אִיסֶרְלָן בְּת''ה סִימָן ד''ש וּבַמַּהֲרִי''ל, וְאֵין לְדַקְדֵּק אַחֲרֵיהֶם.‏

It's not 100% clear to me if he's only referring to Shmitath Kesafim - or to land-related Shmita as well. The language `דְּאֵין שְׁמִטָּה נוֹהֶגֶת בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה` seems rather general, but the issue at hand is monetary as this is part of   הלכות הלוואה and the Siman start with `אֵין שְׁמִטַּת כְּסָפִים נוֹהֶגֶת מִן הַתּוֹרָה`. The  באר היטב  also seems to assume we're dealing with monetary issues:

> **טעם**. גם בתשובת הרא''ש כתב טעם על שהניחם במנהגם ז''ל כיון שפשט המנהג שלא להשמיט והכל יודעים זה ה''ל כאילו התנה המלו' ע''מ שלא תשמט בשביעית עכ''ל. סמ''ע:

That said, the Remo doesn't agree with this view, as you can see from the context - to quote from the beginning of the Siman:

> **א** אֵין שְׁמִטַּת כְּסָפִים נוֹהֶגֶת מִן הַתּוֹרָה אֶלָּא בִּזְמַן שֶׁהַיּוֹבֵל נוֹהֵג. וּמִדִּבְרֵי סוֹפְרִים שֶׁתְּהֵא שְׁמִטַּת כְּסָפִים **נוֹהֶגֶת בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה בְּכָל מָקוֹם**. הגה: (רַמְבַּ''ם פ''ט מֵה' שְׁמִטָּה בעה''ת שַׁעַר מ''ה וְהָרַ''ן בְּשֵׁם יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים) **כֵּן הוּא הַסְכָּמַת הַפּוֹסְקִים** ‏

"All Poskim agree there is Shmita nowadays."

Comment: "כֵּן הוּא הַסְכָּמַת הַפּוֹסְקִים" does not translate to "All Poskim agree there is Shmita nowadays." And I agree with you that the first Rama you quote is only referring to Shemitat Kesafim.